# React state update without key prop: RadioGroup

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a Radio Group and trying to make the radio's button checked value update upon a state update made by clicking another button. In the example below, I can only get the desired effect with the "key" prop. Is there any way to get this API working without the "key" prop:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vfehex?file=index.tsx

Steps to reproduce:
[1] click buttons below RadioField and observe that the Radio doesn't update according to the value
[2] Uncomment in the App the "key" prop on the RadioField
[3] click buttons below the radiofield and observe the radiofield now updates

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

First, add a props inside every `RadioFieldItem` to pass the `selected` value:

```js
      <RadioField
        // LOOK HERE
        // key={selected}
        selectedValue={selected}
      >
        <RadioFieldItem
          selected={selected}
          value="yes"
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
            setSelected(e.target.value)
          }
        />
        <RadioFieldItem
          selected={selected}
          value="no"
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
            setSelected(e.target.value)
          }
        />
        <RadioFieldItem
          selected={selected}
          value="maybe"
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
            setSelected(e.target.value)
          }
        />
      </RadioField>
```

Then, inside the `RadioFieldItem` component use a conditional to check if the selected value is equal than the item name:

```js
export function RadioFieldItem({ value, isDisabled = false, onChange, selected }) {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(generateId());
  const { activeIndex, setActiveIndex } = React.useContext(RadioFieldContext);

  const isRadioSelected = (value: string | undefined): boolean =>
    activeIndex === value;

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setActiveIndex &&
      setActiveIndex((prevState) => {
        onChange && onChange(e);
        return e.target.value;
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name={id}
        id={id}
        value={value}
        checked={selected==value}
        onChange={isDisabled ? undefined : handleChange}
      />
      <label htmlFor={id}>{capitalizeFirstLetter(value)}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: why doesn't the selectedValue from the parent update the children? why do i have to pass selected to radiofield.items?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get it going, but the approach you're taking isn't the best. You're effectively storing two copies of the selected value - once in the `RadioFieldContext`, and once in the local state.

The reason it works with they `key` property is that it forces the `RadioField` component to rerender every time the key changes, so that will internally rebuild the context object, and update the `activeIndex` property.

A better solution would be to only have a single source of truth - the context (`RadioField`). Then, change the context value with the buttons, and read the context value to see what is selected. [Here's a demo using this solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xbnzvd?file=index.tsx).

Comment: thank you! this is really helpful, however one thing to note, this is a design system. i'm shipping the radio-field component and trying to ship it encapsulated. therefore, the consuming team would not have access to the radio-field context

Comment: OK - in that case, move the state management out of the context, and just use the context to propagate it to the children - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xbnzvd?file=index.tsx